# Flag as spam not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, spam

I am trying to flag [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240467/how-do-i-change-an-element-e-g-h1-h2-using-jquery-plain-old-javascript/5465566#5465566) as spam, but after selecting "It is spam" and hitting the "Flag answer" button it just hangs. I've tried many times and let it sit for several minutes before posting here.

I'm using Firefox 4 stable on Ubuntu.

Comment: Same problem marking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034758/what-are-the-best-web-design-sites/5467571#5467571 as spam.

Comment: same here with chrome 12 dev on ubuntu, couldn't figure out why yet

Comment: Hmm did I break something? Checking...

Comment: I tried to flag some of the sandbox post here on meta. it does not work too

Comment: yep, that was me. fixing.

Comment: same with FF18.02, hmm but not hangs just disappears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm prepared to take the blame :)

Fixed now.

Comment: Yup, it works now.